# DNS slow to resolve when browsing, possibly DNS suffix related?

Tags: windows-10, dns, home-networking, netgear-router

and thanks in advance for any help. I am a former software developer, so not technically clueless, but not particularly skilled at networking. I welcome any input on how to to better frame or support my question.

I have a home office setup with multiple computers and devices, running off a Netgear Nighthawk AC1900 connected to Comcast for Internet.

**One Windows 10 PC very often takes "forever" to resolve URLs when browsing the web** — i.e. long enough that Brave shows its "this page seems unresponsive, do you want to continue waiting?" (paraphrased) message while it's trying to connect to a website. **This delay is what I want to get rid of**.

If I reboot the computer in question, it is sometimes quite responsive initially, but inevitably this particular aspect (web pages being painfully slow in resolving when browsing) bogs down. Once connected — e.g. streaming videos or the like —  speed usually seems fine.  it seems to be primarily related to resolving the initial DNS lookup and connecting to the website server.

I have XArp running, and have noticed that both the router and this machine show "hsd1.ca.comcast.net" appended to their device name in the Host column. No other devices show that; they either just show their IP address, or a normal device name (e.g. "SERVER2") with nothing appended.

This problem slows things up often enough it's quite an impediment when browsing the web on this PC. I'd like to figure out how to get it to be consistently responsive and loading webpages. (Note: this seems to be an issue across all browsers on this particular computer.)

Here is the ipconfic /all output from the PC in question:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MOZART
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : hsd1.ca.comcast.net.

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.ca.comcast.net.
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D4-BE-D9-A6-AC-F7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.9(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, July 18, 2023 5:21:45 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, July 19, 2023 5:21:45 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 75.75.75.75
                                       75.75.76.76
                                       0.0.0.0
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

How do I further diagnose and successfully resolve this problem?

Comment: The first thing to try is to use a DNS server other than the ISP's. ISP DNS servers are always worse than alternative popular options. Try changing it to 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare) and/or 8.8.8.8 (Google) and see if its better.

Comment: I did try that at one point (Google) and it didn't seem to solve the issue. That's part of what got me sleuthing into it further and thus discovering the DNS suffix / hostname inconsistencies, which is the only difference I've found so far, this machine vs. others on the same network.